# How to debug a published Asp.net MVC website from hosting internet server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, deployment

I just applied one account from asphostcentral then upload published asp.net mvc application on to that server, but i got an 500 errors, my application is KIGG. I just want to know how can I figure out how can I　view errors in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the site running on IIS6 because if it is then you need to do a bit more work within global.asax.

If it's running on IIS7 then may I suggest you redeploy but include a bunch of debug code.

Answer (score 3):

Don't fully understand your question but...

if you have access to the server and have Visual Studio installed you could debug the code using Attach To Process (Tools menu of Visual Studio) and attach to the IIS app pool process, w3wp.exe

You could also turn on debug info in the web.config file

```
<SafeMode ... CallStack="false" ...> and change it to CallStack="true"
Set <customErrors mode="On" /> to mode="Off"
Set <compilation batch="false" debug="false"> to <compilation batch="true" debug="true">
```

Comment: thanks Simon, I can't attach to w3wp.exe because my website is in a shared hosting machine like: www.aaa.com, i will try your second solution.